# C++ unwanted abort causes?

Tags: c++, gdb, glibc, abort, backtrace

I have a very strange bug in my C++ code.

I must tell you the story to understand the whole.
I'm using threads via boost_thread library. 
The main method makes some initializations, start 3-4 threads and than waits forever:

```
while(true) sleep(1);
```

All the threads' main functions have a try with some catch and a catch all handler:

```
void do_work() {
  try {
    ..
  }
  catch (int ei) {
  }
  catch (...) {
    log("General error");
  }
}
```

The threads do various tasks like

- executing scripts with execv function,
- writing to database with sqlite library,
- communicate with the world via openssl library.

Some times, not usually, but quite frequently to be annoying the program get terminated.

Everything is properly freed and deleted when it should, so this cannot be the problem.
I made it to generate a core dump to have the chance to debug the problem.

The interesting part comes here right now:
the GDB's backtrace looks like this:

```
(gdb) bt
#0  0x40281ae8 in raise () from /lib/libc.so.6
#1  0x402830ec in abort () from /lib/libc.so.6
#2  0x402830ec in abort () from /lib/libc.so.6
#3  0x402830ec in abort () from /lib/libc.so.6
#4  0x402830ec in abort () from /lib/libc.so.6
#5  0x402830ec in abort () from /lib/libc.so.6
#6  0x402830ec in abort () from /lib/libc.so.6
#7  0x402830ec in abort () from /lib/libc.so.6
#8  0x402830ec in abort () from /lib/libc.so.6
#9  0x402830ec in abort () from /lib/libc.so.6
```

Endless abort calls, which I have no idea what causing it.
The threads looks like this:

```
(gdb) info threads
  4 Thread 490  0x402e7bf4 in nanosleep () from /lib/libc.so.6
  3 Thread 489  0x4031b384 in accept () from /lib/libc.so.6
  2 Thread 501  0x402e7bf4 in nanosleep () from /lib/libc.so.6
* 1 Thread 486  0x40281ae8 in raise () from /lib/libc.so.6
```

which is also interesting since thread 1 is the main function with the endless sleeping loop.

My question:
**how can I found out the reason of the abortion (since I cannot ignore it, if I am not mistaken)?**

Searching on forums, IRC channels, and google-ing about it - but still nothing.
I got stuck with this weeks ago, so any information is greatly appreciated!

Thank you very much!

Comment: Have you tried sticking a breakpoint at the top of abort (`b abort`)?

Comment: Not yet, I will! Thank you :)
It's btw a bit difficult since there are situations when this bug does not show up for days..

Comment: This program sounds like a very good candidate to run under valgrind.  If there is heap corruption going on (e.g. due to a race condition between threads), valgrind might lead you to the source of the problem.

Comment: I will valgrind it, thank you! I think I should redirect to valgrind's output to file, since sometimes it takes days to head up again.

Comment: If you `set height 0`, the `bt` command will continue printing the backtrace without prompting for pagination. What is at the bottom of the call stack?

Comment: The call stack is full of abort calls. I set the height to 0, now it digs down until ~1400 calls without any change.

Answer (score 1):

SIGABRT is usually sent when things go terribly, terribly wrong. They can be hard to track down because the stack might well be trashed.

From the traceback, it looks like you are running with a stripped (and probably optimized) executable. Have you tried compiling and linking with `-g` so that when you do get the coredump you can gain a bit more insight?

Comment: Yes, it's a stripped one, I compiled it now with the symbols etc, to get a bit more info. I'll upload the new backtrace here when the bug comes again. But I think it won't help too much since the abort function is not in my code, and the backtrace is full with that :(

Comment: That traceback may be completely munged because I suspect you trashed the stack. Stack overflow, perhaps.

Comment: any solution about this problem,i reallly needed it?